# House Drawing with java (console)

Tags: java, console

I have to make a program that asks the user to input a height and a length (both even numbers), and then the program will draw a house. The roof of the house is (width/2) number of rows. Sample program should look like this:

```
Enter height and width of the house you want me to draw (must be even numbers): 10 10
....**
.../..\
../....\
./......\
/........\
----------
|........|
|........|
|........|
|........|
|........|
|........|
|........|
|........|
|........|
|........|
----------
```

but this is what i keep getting for the roof only, using 10 and 10 for width and height (i havent started the body yet):

```
height: 10
width: 10

....**
.../..\
.../..\
.../..\
.../..\
----------
```

**Does anyone know how I can place the correct amount of space to make it look like the sample?** my code is:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuestionCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int height = 0, width = 0;

        String space = ".", left = "/", right = "\\";

        System.out.print("height: ");
        height = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("width: ");
        width = keyboard.nextInt();


        System.out.println();

        int outerSpace = ((width/2)-1);

        int halfWidth = ((width/2)-2);

        while (outerSpace > 0) {
            System.out.print(space);
            --outerSpace;
        }

        System.out.println("**");

        while (halfWidth >= 0) {

            outerSpace = ((width/2)-2);

            while (outerSpace > 0) {
                System.out.print(space);
                --outerSpace;
            }

            System.out.print(left);
            int innerSpace = 2;

            while (innerSpace < (width-2)) {
                System.out.print(space);
                innerSpace *= 2;
            }

            System.out.println(right);
            halfWidth--;
        }

        while (width > 0) {
            System.out.print("-");
            --width;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider this: Your roof obviously needs a slope, so in each row, how much space is inbetween the left border and the beginning of the roof depends on how far down we are. That means that the current row must inevitably factor into the calculation that tells you how many points you ought to draw there.

Comment: Maybe you should consider using 'for' loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here under you'll find a proposition for doing it using `for` loops.

It is much more efficient in this type of exercice because you know in advance how many times you're going to loop.

Basically, I'm using two other variables other than `width` and `height` that are :

`heightRoof` : to know how many rows I wanna have for my rooftop.

`middle` : to know how many points I have to draw on the first line before stopping.

From there, using nested loops is the way to go because We know exactly how many points and rows we want to have, the rest is *logical thinking*.

```
        int width = 10;
        int height = 10;

        int middle = width % 2 == 0 ? (width / 2) - 1 : width / 2;
        int heightRoof = middle+1;

        for (int i = 0 ; i < heightRoof ; i++){
            for (int j = middle - i - 1 ; j >= 0 ; j--){
                System.out.print(".");
            }
            if (i == 0) {
                System.out.print("**");
                System.out.println();
                continue;
            } else {
                System.out.print("/");
                for (int k = 0 ; k < 2*i ; k++){
                    System.out.print(".");
                }
            }
            System.out.print("\\");
            System.out.println();
        }

        for (int i = 0 ; i < width ; i++){
            System.out.print("-");
        }
```

Comment: IT WORKED!! I wasn't going to use "for" loops at first because the assignment said we should try NOT to use them (i have no idea why), but i worked out the code with your help and it worked :D thank you!!